# Is there a more efficient way to subset time series data frame on irregular, repeated binary trigger column?

Tags: r

I am working with a time-series data stream from an experiment. We record multiple data channels, including a trigger channel ('X7.ramptrig' in linked data: Time-Series Data Example), that indicates when a relevant event occurs in other channels.

I am trying to create subsets of the next n-rows (e.g. 15,000) of the time-series (time steps are 0.1ms) that occur after onset of a trigger ('1'). That column has multiple triggers ('1') interspersed at irregular intervals. Every other time step is a '0', indicating no new event.

I am asking to see if there is a more efficient solution to directly subset the subsequent n-rows after a trigger is detected instead of the indirect (possibly inflexible) solution I have come up with.

Link to simple example data:
https://gtvault-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/shousley6_gatech_edu/EZZSVk6pPpJPvE0fXq1W2KkBhib1VDoV_X5B0CoSerdjFQ?e=izlkml

I have a working solution that creates an index from the trigger channel and splits the dataset on that index. Because triggers have variability in placement in time, the subsequent data frame subsets are not consistent and there are occasionally 'extra' subsets that precede 'important' ones ('res$0' in example). Additionally, I need to have the subsets be matched for total time and aligned for trigger onset.

My current solution 'cuts' the lists of data frames to the same size (in the example to the first 15,000 rows). While this technically works it seems clunky. I also tried to translate a SQL solution using FETCH NEXT but those functions are not available in the SQLite supported in R.

I am completely open to alternatives so please be unconstrained by my current solution.

```
##create index to detect whenever an event trigger occurs 
idx<-c(0, cumsum(diff(Time_Series_Data_Example$X7.ramptrig) >0))

## split the original dataframe on event triggers
split1<-split(Time_Series_Data_Example, idx) 

## cuts DFs down to 1.5s 
res <- lapply(split1, function(x){ 
  x <- top_n(x, -15000) 
})
```

Here is an example of data output: 'head(res[["1"]]' [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd2Zl.png)

For the example data and code provided, the output is 4 subsets, 3 of which are 'important' and time synced to the trigger. The first 'res$0' is a throw away subset.

Thanks in advance and please let me know how I can improve my question asking (this is my first attempt).

Comment: Possible to show a small example of the desired output?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I edited the original post to include a brief example of output.

Comment: Is something important going to happen in the 1.5 sec packets or are they just convenient sizes? You might want Postgresql rather than SQLite, and would probably find r package tsmp and all papers out of [UC Riverside](https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/) of interest for both off line and real time analysis, that may obviate the need to create equal sized data.frames.

Comment: Ok so it seems like subsets 2 to 4 are desirable? That the 1st is not - so basically make it so that subset 1's never appear and only desired output of subsets 2 to 4? Seems like your close with your own version - or how can you see the improvement from here?

Comment: Chris- thank you for taking a look and giving me some feedback. I will look into Keogh's work. Yes, in these experiments the 1.5 second packets dictate important events, because we impose them. We are moving away from these stereotyped events so that is why I am worried about its inflexibility. Hopefully Keogh's work will provide some inspiration.